# how to get "id" and "text" in the given object coming from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to get id and text values . can anyone solve this.
how to get text and id values
this data is coming from api

```
useEffect(()=>{
    let baseUrl='fakeapi';
     fetch(`/${baseUrl}/getTodos`)
     .then(res=>res.json())
     .then(data=>{
         console.log(data)
         setData(data )
        }) 
},[])
```

[image: this is data coming from api]

Comment: May you share a [mcve] of how you get this data?

Comment: {todos: Array(1)}
todos: Array(1)
0: {id: 1, text: "hello 1"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object

Comment: please edit the question